# How to increase the font size of the printed line by using python script?

Tags: python

I have wrote python code where I am displaying a line on output screen.

```
#!/pro/mobile/Linux/bin/python

print '\033[1m \033[91m \033[4m' +  "SELECTED OPTION IS FOR INSERTING\n" + '\033[0m'
print "Please enter valid input\n"
```

Here I have used '**\033[1m \033[91m \033[4m**' for making the line bold, change the color of line to red and underline. These are all ok and it works fine.

But here i am unable to increase the font size of the line. I have to increase the of **first line** which will get displayed on **same terminal**, second line will be displayed in default font size of the terminal.
Please help me to increase the font size of the line.

Comment: Are you sure this is a dupe?  The OP has "linux" in the comment, a unix path, and escape sequences that AFAIK don't work on windows -- yet the dupe target says "Change console font in **Windows**"

Comment: @Ben Hi Ben.. I found how to increase font size in python by using Tkinter , but in this i have used different GUI.. But here I am using putty and in want that font size should be increase on same putty screen not on different screen. please don't get confuse with increasing putty font size by going to properties tab. that will be different..

Comment: @Tichodroma I found how to increase font size in python by using Tkinter , but in this i have used different GUI.. But here I am using putty and in want that font size should be increase on same putty screen not on different screen. please don't get confuse with increasing putty font size by going to properties tab. that will be different..

Comment: @Michael I found how to increase font size in python by using Tkinter , but in this i have used different GUI.. But here I am using putty and in want that font size should be increase on same putty screen not on different screen. please don't get confuse with increasing putty font size by going to properties tab. that will be different..

Comment: I am just a begineer to python so please bear me for asking question.